# Having trouble with JTable and JModel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, abstracttablemodel

This is my ClanModel class. The table is based on a tree map.

```
public class ClanModel extends AbstractTableModel{
    private Map<Integer, ClanMember> clanMembers;
    private final String[] columnNames = {"Name", "Rank"};

    ClanModel(Map<Integer, ClanMember> clanMembers){
        this.clanMembers = clanMembers;
    }   

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return clanMembers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column){
        return columnNames[column]; 
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        if(column == 0) return clanMembers.get(row).getName();
        if(column == 1) return clanMembers.get(row).getRank();
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
        if(column == 0) clanMembers.get(row).setName((String) value);
        if(column == 1) clanMembers.get(row).setRank((Rank) value);
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
    }
}
```

This is in the gui constructor

```
clanTable = new JTable(new ClanModel(clanMembers));
panel.add(clanTable);
```

The map is filled on a button press which is working. However, the table doesn't appear before clicking the button or after. I also get an error every time I resize the gui window.

I have a rough idea of what I need to do to fix it but it hasn't been working out.

Comment: I don't see `invokeLater()` or `setVisible()`. Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: What error do you get upon resizing the GUI? Also, is the `Container` in which the `JTable` is in added somewhere in your `Window`?

Comment: He's probably not getting an error; having to resize the frame to get an implicit `repaint()` is probably caused by an errant `setVisible()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving `setVisible()` so that it's *after* `add()` and `pack()`. See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JTable table = new JTable(new ClanModel(…));
            f.add(new JScrollPane(table));
            f.pack();
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```